# Different values in an custom entity field for each domain?

Tags: 9, domain-access

I have implemented the [Domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module and added a boolean custom field to a taxonomy entity that is accessible in all three domains: domain1.example.com, domain2.example.com, and domain3.example.com. However, I am facing an issue where updating the field value in one domain affects all the other domains. I want to have the ability to save different values for this field in each individual domain. Is there any way to achieve this?